# ¿Cómo puedo corregir el error «truncated incorrect integer value» al intentar insertar datos en la base de datos?

Tags: java, mysql

Ocupo un poco de ayuda para poder solucionar el error ya dicho, estoy haciendo un programa en netbeans llamado ShopIronWork, este mismo lo conecte con MySQL-Workbench, todo esta bien solo que al guardar los datos  me marca el siguente error:

> "Incorrect integer value: for column "Codigo_material" at row 1.

Este error es producido una vez ingreso los valores y los guardo.
este es el código de el botón guardar en mi tabla almacén:

```
{
    Connection reg = conexionConBaseDatos.getConexion();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Almacen(Codigo_material, Cantidad_material)VALUES(?,?)";
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = reg.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, txtCódM.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtC.getText());
            int n = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (n>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registrado Exitosamnete El Articulo");

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error no se grabo el Registro - "+e);
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En lugar de poner imágenes pon el texto del código, con imágenes no se puede reproducir el problema. El error es porque la columna es del tipo `INT` en la tabla, entonces debes usar `setInt`  en la consulta preparada y convertir el valor obtenido a entero. Debes decirnos qué tipo de dato son las columnas `Codigo_material` y `Cantidad_material` en la tabla.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Julio, esta no es la forma adecuada de preguntar en el sitio, es importante que antes revises [ask] y modifiques tu pregunta, aquí también puedes reprobar en tu pregunta x/ (es broma). Realiza el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento. Con respecto a tu pregunta el valor que introduces en txtCodM debe ser numerico.

Comment: Seria mucho mas facil ayudarte si pusieras el codigo en lugar de la imagen, ademas le falta seriedad a tu pregunta nadie la tomara en serio, por otra parte tu error es que estas capturando un string y la sentencia espera un entero, solo debes hacer un cast a int, Integer.parseInt(txt.getText.toString)

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, soy nuevo y me gusta mucho esta comunidad por lo tanto veré bien como puedo formular preguntas.

Comment: Veo que te han votado negativo en la pregunta, no te desanimes por ello. Mejórala, cambia el título, comparte el código en vez de imágenes e inserta las columnas que sean del tipo `INT` usando `setInt` y convirtiendo a entero  los valores que obtienes para insertar en esas columnas. Verás que se pasa el desmayo y que no suspendes. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo con el tiempo seguiré aprendiendo como formular preguntas etc, aunque al cambiar el código como me dijo me marca el siguiente error: java.lang.NumberFormatExeption: for input string: """

Comment: Julio en estos casos es muy importante controlar lo que el usuario escribe, el mismo es imprevisible y puede escribir cualquier cosa. Revisa la respuesta, he puesto un método de validación para cuando haya valores inconvertibles a entero.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje dice que la columna `Codigo_material` es del tipo `INT` en la tabla (si `Cantidad_material` también lo es debes aplicar la solución expuesta más abajo también para esa columna).

### Solución:

- Convertir el valor que obtienes a entero. Dado que **el usuario es imprevisible**, debes tener un método de validación, aquí he agregado uno muy sencillo que devuelve el valor por defecto que le mandes cuando el valor no sea *convertible válidamente*.
- Usar el método `setInt` para pasarlo a la consulta preparada.

Inténtalo así:

```
    Connection reg = conexionConBaseDatos.getConexion();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Almacen(Codigo_material, Cantidad_material)VALUES(?,?)";
        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = reg.prepareStatement(sql);
            /*
              *Aquí pasamos el valor que el usuario escribió
              *al método parseWithDefault para que lo convierta a entero
              *si hay un valor incorrecto, le decimos al método que
              *nos devuelva el valor 0
             */   
            int codMaterial = parseWithDefault(txtCódM.getText(),0);
            pst.setInt(1, codMaterial);
            /*
              *Si Cantidad_material fuese también entero
              *debes hacer algo parecido:
              *  int cantMaterial = parseWithDefault(txtC.getText(),0);
              *  pst.setInt(2,cantMaterial);
            */
            pst.setString(2, txtC.getText());
            int n = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (n>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registrado Exitosamnete El Articulo");

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error no se grabo el Registro - "+e);
        }  

/*
  *Este es el método que validará los enteros
  *Nótese que este tipo de métodos conviene tenerlos en clases utilitarias
*/

public static int parseWithDefault(String number, int defaultVal) {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(number);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return defaultVal;
  }
}
```

---

#### Otra posibilidad

Sería hacer depender la inserción de que el usuario haya escrito valores mayores que cero. Entonces, el código sería así:

```
int codMaterial = parseWithDefault(txtCódM.getText(),0);
int cantMaterial = parseWithDefault(txtC.getText(),0);
String msj;

if (codMaterial > 0 && cantMaterial > 0) {
    Connection reg = conexionConBaseDatos.getConexion();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Almacen(Codigo_material, Cantidad_material)VALUES(?,?)";
    try{
            PreparedStatement pst = reg.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setInt(1,codMaterial);
            pst.setInt(2,cantMaterial);
            int n = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (n>0){
                msj="Registrado Exitosamnete El Articulo";
            }
    }catch (Exception e){
            msj="Error no se grabo el Registro - "+e;
    }      
}else{
    msj="Los datos escritos no son válidos para insertar";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msj);
```

> **NOTA:** Evita usar acentos en los nombres de variables, por ejemplo aquí `txtCódM`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo y paciencia, ya me sirvió su método y lo aplicare en todas mis tablas gracias y buen día/tarde o noche.